# Report columns overlap with each other

Tags: reporting-services, telerik-reporting

I've been having this problem for a while now, in some parts of my report the columns overlap, no matter what I do on the styling I still can't fix it. Here's how it looks:

[image: With Borders:]

[image: Without borders]

EDIT:

I'd also like to add that this issue is inconsistent. This mostly happens when opening the report on Google Chrome but it doesnt happen on Edge. Also there are zoom levels that the layout is fixed for example if I zoom about 150% the layout gets fixed.

Also I think what's strange is that only the colored columns overlaps. As you can see the columns with just white background are working well.

Comment: It looks like you removed the border from the table but are there any borders on the individual text boxes? Once you get over a 1 pt border, the pixels have to bleed somewhere.

Comment: @HannoverFist that's the thing, there are no borders on the individual textboxes. The borders you see on the first image is on the whole table not the textbox. On the second image, there are no borders on anything there from the table to the individual textboxes. That's why it's hard to identify why it's overlapping.